# Modifying AJAX from insert to update if modal is clicked again

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I've built a CMS that uses bootstrap Modals within div areas so that when the user clicks on the div where they want to insert content, a modal comes up with a tinyMCE text editor area where they can put images or text. Once they have, they hit the save button in the modal which closes the modal and shows the preview of what they just did.

Also, when they hit the save button, I perform an AJAX request that calls an addPanel.php script in order to insert a record for that panel, panel type and content.

THis works perfectly except for the fact that if they click on the modal again and do this all over to edit their content, it just saves another panel.

I need to slightly modify what I"m doing now to either:

1. Get the ID of the panel that was created on the last ajax request and now perform a mysql update on the record for the content (as the panel ID and panel type will remain the same)
2. Keep the current process but set the last panel's 'active' column in mysql to '0' (not as big a fan of this approach but will accept it).

Basically, what I have works but if the user clicks on the modal anymore after the first time, I would be updating instead of inserting.

Here is the mysql being performed in addPanel.php:

```
$content = $_POST['page_content'];

$addContent = "
    INSERT INTO content(content)
    VALUES('$content');
";

if ($mysqlConn->query($addContent) === TRUE) {
    $cont_id = $mysqlConn->insert_id;
    $data['last_insert_id'] = $cont_id;
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $addContent . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
}

$panelID = $_POST['panel_type'];
$pageID = $_POST['page_id'];
$addPanel = "
    INSERT INTO panels(panel_type_id, page_id, cont_id)
    VALUES ('$panelID', '$pageID', '$cont_id');
";

if ($mysqlConn->query($addPanel) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $addPanel . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
}
```

And the script/AJAX to show an example of what I'm doing currently for a panel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#leftHalfForm").submit(function(e){

    var leftContentVar = tinymce.get("leftHalfTextArea").getContent();

    $(".leftContent").html(leftContentVar);
    $("#leftHalfPageContent").val(leftContentVar);

    // jQuery.noConflict();

      var string = $('#leftHalfForm').serialize() + '&page_id=' + page_id;
      console.log(string);


    // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addPanel.php",
            data: string,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
              console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
              console.log(string);


              $('#leftFiftyModal').modal('hide');
              $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
            }
        });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: In your PHP code before $addPanel usage you need to check if the record with panel id already exists. And if exists run UPDATE sql instead of INSERT

Comment: Could you give an example? Because when this is submitted and calls my php/mysql code, it creates a content record and uses the content ID to create a panel record. So I guess I would have to also grab the panel ID and save it then use it in the ajax as well?

Comment: Consider using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in  your SQL INSERT call. Much cleaner and easier and you won't have to worry about how many times they click on the button. Or simply disable the button until your AJAX call is complete.

Comment: @TomN. Yes, you need to grab the panel id and add it to the `string` variable in your JS code.

Comment: @IvnH ok so I guess I can do this similar to what I'm doing already for page and content IDs. So then I would alter my mysql code to just use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Comment: @TomN. Yes, exactly as Dave suggested.

Comment: I will try this now, thanks you two! If either of you want to make this into an answer I'll gladly accept it

Comment: @IvnH I just realized, I have two divs with modals doing this so just keeping the Id of the last update would t be reliable would it?

Comment: @TomN. sorry I don't see what is the purpose of using two divs. I guess, in your panels you need to store panel id (using data attribute). And send this data with your ajax request. On server side (PHP) you check if the panel id is empty or not and perform insert or update according to that.